# JAVA method return something then send email

Tags: java

Here is my code:

```
public String addxyz ()
{
    String returnStatus = "";
    DBConnection conn = new DBConnection();
    returnStatus = conn.fun_GetData();

    ArrayList<String> emailList = new ArrayList<String>();
    emailList.add("xyz@gmail.com");
    emailList.add("asd@hotmail.com");

    for(String email : emailList)
    {
        SendEmail sendEmail = new SendEmail();
        boolean statusEmail = sendEmail.SendingEmail(email);
    }

    return returnStatus;
}
```

I want to know what is the best way to send email to every email address after returning method status.

For example I have 100 email list so the above method is first sending 100 email then return status.

But i want to return something then send email so is that possible?

Comment: What's the point of that status if it cannot change inside the function? Also, what's the point of the parameter qweqw ??

Comment: @Fildor its just an example.

Comment: Please add where the status is changed because that highly affects the possibilities of what can be done here.

Comment: @Fildor i update my question, please check it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to send emails asynchronously then.

You can very well right a multi threaded program wherein  you are sending emails in a different executor thread and main thread returns back with a status without getting blocked on sending the emails.

You can use Java Executors api for this one.

Comment: can you write code for it, because i am not good on multi threaded.

Answer (score 0):

For multi threading you can do like this:

```
public String addxyz (String qweqw)
{
    String returnStatus = "status";
    ArrayList<String> emailList = new ArrayList<String>();
    emailList.add("xyz@gmail.com");
    emailList.add("asd@hotmail.com");

        for(String email : emailList)
        {
            // create a thread
            Thread th = new Thread(){           
                @Override
                public void run(){

                    // Your SendMail logic
                    SendEmail sendEmail = new SendEmail();
                    boolean statusEmail = sendEmail.SendingEmail(email);
                }           
            };

            th.start(); // start the thread & continue to next email
        }

        return returnStatus;
}
```

Comment: It's just a demo for, how to use multi threading in this case.
Well - One Thread for each email is not an optimal solution.

Comment: Please follow this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11408269/java-mail-using-executorservice

Answer (score 0):

From the snippet in your question, the status and parameter seem completely useless. So you could do:

```
// in main execution path
String returnStatus = "status";
new Thread( new Runnable() {
  @Override public void run(){ addxyz("dummy"); }
 } ).start();
```

But I really doubt that this will work out. I guess your example misses where and why status could be changed in the function. Then this solution is void!

### UPDATE

From the point where your status won't change inside the function, you can wrap the rest in a Thread/Runnable and run it. For example:

```
....
returnStatus = conn.fun_GetData();

new Thread( new Runnable() { @Override public void run() {
    ArrayList<String> emailList = new ArrayList<String>();
    emailList.add("xyz@gmail.com");
    emailList.add("asd@hotmail.com");

    for(String email : emailList)
    {
        SendEmail sendEmail = new SendEmail();
        boolean statusEmail = sendEmail.SendingEmail(email);
    }
}}).start();

return returnStatus;
```

In Java 8 you can also use Lambda:

```
new Thread( () -> {
  // your code here
} ).start();
```